# Как сделать кастомное правило валидации в vee-validate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как сделать кастомное правило валидации в vee-validate ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

[creating-a-custom-rule](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html#creating-a-custom-rule)

Вот ссылка как это сделать в самой документации. Если в двух словах тебе приходит в функцию значение и в зависимости от твоего выбора ты возвращаешь true или false